# Is there a way to convert Array Ref as String to an actual Array ref in Perl? - Can't use string("ARRAY(...)") as an ARRAY ref

Tags: arrays, string, perl, reference

I am getting an Array reference as a String Value in my subroutine

Is there a way to convert it to an actual array reference in Perl?

The error that I am seeing is:

Failed to process for the following reason: *Can't use string ("ARRAY(0x7fe81abebd68)") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ..*

I need to use a value from this array ref that is coming as a String.

Comment: There is an error in your use of variable and references. This does not surprise you. But if you want more details, then please show the code you are describing. Please provide a [mre]. (Actually you do not even describe your code.... but you know what I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to convert a stringified reference back into a real, usable reference.  You need to examine the code which is giving you the stringified reference and fix it so that the reference doesn't get coerced into a string in the first place.  (If you edit the question to include the code in question - or, better, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - then we can probably help you to fix it.)

Comment: unsmash_av in http://p3rl.org/Devel::Pointer::PP (but don't do that)